# Spring boot - Bean not found accurs while autowiring dependency

Tags: spring-boot

i'm using springboot 1.5.13

This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment")
public class PaymentResource {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Autowired
   private UserPaymentService userPaymentService;

   @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity addNewCreditCardPost (
        @RequestBody UserPayment userPayment,
        Principal principal) {
      User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

      UserBilling userBilling = userPayment.getUserBilling();

      userService.updateUserBilling(userBilling, userPayment, user);

      return new ResponseEntity("Payment Added(Updated) Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
   }

   @RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity removePaymentPost(
        @RequestBody String id,
        Principal principal
        ){
// User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

      userPaymentService.removeById(Long.valueOf(id));

      return new ResponseEntity("Payment Removed Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
   }

   @RequestMapping(value="/setDefault", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity setDefaultPaymentPost(
        @RequestBody String id,
        Principal principal
        ){
      User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

      userService.setUserDefaultPayment(Long.parseLong(id), user);

      return new ResponseEntity("Payment Removed Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
   }

   @RequestMapping("/getUserPaymentList")
   public List<UserPayment> getUserPaymentList(
        Principal principal
        ){
      User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

      List<UserPayment> userPaymentList = user.getUserPaymentList();

      return userPaymentList;
   }

}
```

This is my interface :

```
public interface UserPaymentService {

   UserPayment findById(Long id);

   void removeById(Long id);
}
```

I'm Getting this problem when i'm trying to run program:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description: Field userPaymentService in com.sovimal.bookstore.resource.PaymentResource required a bean of type 'com.sovimal.bookstore.service.UserPaymentService' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sovimal.bookstore.service.UserPaymentService' in your configuration.
```

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: what class implements UserPaymentService?

Comment: Did you implement the `UserPaymentService` interface and mark it as a Spring stereotype (`@Component` / `@Service`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add @Service annotaion in your service class and try again.

```
@Service
public interface UserPaymentService {

   UserPayment findById(Long id);

   void removeById(Long id);
}
```